# How to add a function of ConfigureService of Startup to old version MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a problem about my project and I found possible solution in a .NET Core blog. But, unfortunately, my project is using ASP.NET MVC 5. I don't know where should I put this code to.

The code is below

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
  services.AddSingleton(HtmlEncoder.Create(allowedRanges: new[] { UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin, 
  UnicodeRanges.Latin1Supplement, UnicodeRanges.LatinExtendedA }));           
 }
```

Comment: The code is to register a service (using Dependency Injection). Are you trying to apply DI in your project?

Comment: Actually I am trying to fix special char problem on viewsource screen. I tried everything and that  code for it

Comment: What special chars you want to fix? And what is the problem with the char?

Comment: the special characters are ü ğ i ö ü ç in my project. And problem is they looks normal in chrome Inspect screen but they dont looks normal(they looks such as &#220) in viewsource:// screen (ctrl+u)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IServiceCollection` is a type used to collect service registrations. You don’t by default have `IServiceCollection` in ASP.NET MVC 5 like ASP.NET Core does. (You could install via nuget packages)

You could add / register `HtmlEncoder` to your DI container builder. If you don’t have one, take a look at example below see how to setup one for your app.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-5/